# Partial deserialization of std::map

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Are there any ways to do partial deserialization of std::map that was serialized with boost::archive::text_oarchive and then saved to file?
For example we have a big serialized and saved map where key is integer and value is some structure and now we need to get it back by parts... load first 100 records, then load next 100 records... etc. 
Are there any libs, boost classes or solutions to do it?

Comment: Why do you now need to get it back in parts?  If it's because you want your thread to not be tied up, then start another to do it and raise a signal when you're done

Comment: Because our serialized map now is too big and sometimes we have problems when we are trying to deserialize it and put into memory in one part.

Comment: In that case, Donghui gave you the answer - you need to find a machine where you can deserialise it, and then re-serialise it in a new format that matches your new modular design.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the same serialize() function is called both to serialize and to deserialize. If you want to get it back in parts, you should serialize it in parts in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately we already have that big serialized map and now we are faced with a problem when we are trying to load it in one part.

Comment: An easy solution is to deserialize the whole map, and copy parts out. A hard-core solution is to understand the format of the serialized result -- possibly through studying the source code of how a map is serialized and how your key and value types are serialized -- and write a special deserialize function. I believe it is doable but I'd strongly push back on choosing that approach.

Comment: I'm with Donghui Zhang

Comment: Thanks again but now we just need to find out are there any ready-to-use solutions and as far as I understand the answer is no.